# Is it possible to download archived contentversion or contentDocument

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, contentversion, contentdocument

I am having a hard time downloading a contentversion/contentdocument where contentdocument is already archived.

I am trying to download the file by hitting rest endpoint

```
services/data/v44.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/068L0000000RgEkIAK/VersionData
```

with Authorization header.

The response i got is

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to download the files.
Is it possible to download archived content. The file needs to be sent to another non salesforce domain.

In my browser, If i directly go to contentversion url, `https://**-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/_classic/%2F068L0000000RgEvIAK` then
the file gets downloaded.

**Edit**: I can get the contentVersion by setting isArchived of contentdocument to false

```
ContentDocument doc= [select id,IsArchived from ContentDocument where IsArchived=false and id = '069L0000000RZb0IAG'  ALL ROWS];
ContentVersion cv = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion where contentdocumentId = :doc.id and islatest=true ALL ROWS];
```

But I do not want to set isArchived to false again as that would fail other logic.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Why can't you download the files? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Are you able to download non archived version?

Comment: I received, "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND", "message": "The requested resource does not exist" message.

If I open the contentversion directly (https://**-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/_classic/%2F068L0000000RgEvIAK/068L0000000RgEvIAK) in  the domain, the file gets downloaded.
(Updated question)
Any way i can solve this problem.

Comment: is that contentDocument attached to a record or in a library?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I have updated question. Can you plz help.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal The document is now archived and is present in library but cannot be downloaded, as said in this documentation but not very sure :).
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_delete.htm&type=0

Comment: I couldn't find any specific documentation around it but based on a quick test, that seems to be the behavior while extracting archived Content using REST API. This could be most likely related to that an archived content is not available in search results.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I too am trying to download the archived data, I can get the latest published content version id but I get the resource not found error, I suppose I could unarchive and the rearchive? I'll try that if I don't find another way :)